# grails unit test with JSON RestfulController

Tags: grails

I am having an issue writing unit test for a simple controller and really looking for help.

My controller:

```
package test.controller

import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.rest.RestfulController;
import grails.transaction.Transactional
import groovy.sql.GroovyRowResult
import groovy.sql.Sql
import javax.sql.DataSource

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class ProjectController extends RestfulController {
    javax.sql.DataSource dataSource
    def projectService
    static responseFormats = ['json']

    def hello() {
        respond 'hello'
    }

    // project_vm is a db view and I coud not figure out mapping a domain for db view, so using sql
    def list(){
        Sql db = new Sql(dataSource)
        def result
        if (params.manager) {
            result = db.rows("SELECT * FROM project_vm where manager=:manager", [manager:params.manager])
        }else{
            result = db.rows("SELECT * FROM project_vm")
        }
        respond result
    }
```

Works fine from browser:

```
http://myhost/testproject/project/list
===>
[{"name":"prj1","manager":"testmanagerId1"}, {"name":"prj2","manager":"testmanagerId2"}]
```

But unit test is failing with following error. I am using mysql.

```
package test.controller

import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin
import spock.lang.Specification
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import test.domain.Project


@TestFor(ProjectController)
@Mock(Project)
class ProjectControllerSpec extends Specification {
    void "test something"() {
        given:
        new Project(name:"testproject", manager:"managerId").save(flush:true)

        when:
        request.method = 'GET'
        response.format = 'json'
        controller.list()

        then:
        response.status == 200
        (response.text).contains('testproject')
    }
}
```

Error I am getting is:

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method groovy.sql.Sql#<init>.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [interface java.sql.Connection]
    [interface javax.sql.DataSource]
    at test.controller.ProjectController.$tt__list(ProjectController.groovy:37)
    at test.controller.ProjectControllerSpec.test something(ProjectControllerSpec.groovy:21)
```

Comment: Unit tests don't run in a fully-configured Grails environment (ie. no dependency injection happens, so your `dataSource` reference is null)  In your case, I would suggest using an integration test rather than a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest switching to Grails Api Toolkit which has api abstraction. Your tests will need to be done across the architecture eventually (ie proxy, message queue, etc) and not just on application and tying everything to controllers means tests are localized.

Grails Api Toolkit allows for shared concern in architecture; functionality and data for api are moved to communication layer where they can be shared, cached and read across all components.

For more, see the SpringOne slideshare on this...

http://www.slideshare.net/bobdobbes/api-abstraction-api-chaining